# Is using video memory in GPU or FPGA as circular buffer for display a good idea?

Tags: gpu, fpga

The circular buffer is to display image in a window. Since reading/writing the buffer for display would take some time, I read an article about using GPU video memory or FPGA VGA SRAM as circular buffer.

But one problem I can see is that there is no easy way to pass that video memory (pointer) to UI API such as MFC or Qt. In order to do that, we need to copy the content to normal RAM which loses its purpose.

So I wonder if it is a good idea to use video memory in GPU or FPGA as circular buffer for display. If so, how can I overcome the issue above? Any clue from experienced developer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is always a good idea to use a double buffer for video memory. But it depends on your system if the necessary memory bandwidth is avalible.